# PHP, MySQL and a large nummer of simple queries

Tags: php, mysqli, persistent

I'm implementing an application that will have a lot of clients querying lots of small data packages from my webserver. Now I'm unsure whether to use persistent data connections to the database or not. The database is currently on the same system as the webserver and could connect via the socket, but this may change in the near future.

As I know a few releases of PHP ago mysqli_pconnect was removed because it behaved suboptimally. In the meantime it seems to be back again.

Based on my scenario I suppose I won't have an other chance to handle thousands of queries per minute but with loads of persistent connections and a MySQL configuration that reserves only little resources per connection, right?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Note that all clients sharing the persistent connection also share the temporary tables created on it (the temp tables don't get recycled until the connection does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened when you tested it?

With the nest will in the world, there's no practical way you can convey all the informaton required for people to provide a definitive answer in a SO response. However *usually* there is very little overhead in establishing a mysql connection, particularly if it resides on the same system as the database client (in this case the webserver). There's even less overhead if you use a filesystem rather than a network socket.

So I'd suggest abstracting all your database calls so you can easily switch between connection types, but write your system to use on-demand connections, and ensure you code explicitly releases the connection as soon as practical - then see how it behaves.

C.

Comment: Okay, thanks! It's not easy to test the scenario. I just want to be prepared instead of immediately running into problems.

Answer (score 1):

[Are PHP persistant connections evil?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/)

> The problem is there can be only so
>   many connections active between Host
>   “Apache” and Host “MySQL”

Persistant connections usually give problems in that you hit the maximum number of connections. Also, in your case it does not give a great benefit since your database server is on the same host. Keep it to normal connections for now.

Answer (score 1):

As they say, your mileage may vary, but I've never had good experiences using persistent connections from PHP, including MySQL and Oracle (both ODBC and OCI8). Every time I've tested it, the system fails to reuse connections. With high load, I end up hitting the top limit while I have hundreds of idle connections.

So my advice is that you actually try it and find out whether your set-up is reusing connections properly. If it isn't working as expected, it won't be a big lose anyway: opening a MySQL connection is not particularly costly compared to other DBMS.

Also, don't forget to reset all relevant settings when appropriate (whatever session value you change, it'll be waiting for you next time to stablish a connection and happen to reuse that one).